# Word that corresponds to "flew" or "drove" when riding a train

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

My daughter recently journeyed several hundred miles by rail.

Had she taken a bus, I could say:

> *"She was **bussed** from San Francisco to Houston"*

Had she flown in an airplane, I could say:

> *"She **flew** from San Francisco to Houston"*

Of course, these definitions are recognized by the dictionary; from NOAD:

> **fly** (*verb*) transport in an aircraft
>   **bus** (*verb*) transport in a communal road vehicle

While talking to a friend about her trip, though, I found myself wondering if there's a similar verb used to describe transportation by rail.

Obviously, there are plenty of ways to say it – I'm not asking for one of these:

> *"She **took a train** from San Francisco to Houston"
>
>   "She **rode on a train** from San Francisco to Houston"*

Instead, I'm wondering if a single verb could do the trick.

I did consider the verb *railroad*:

> *She was **railroaded** from San Francisco to Houston*.

but I was hoping for a better word than that, because that verb generally connotes something other than travel:

> **railroad** (*verb*) press (someone) into doing something by rushing or coercing

Comment: Sounds like she was railed.

Comment: When I send something large by train, I **ship** it. Figure that one out and get back to us...

Comment: *Bused*, not *bussed*!

Comment: @ErikE - [dictionaries](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/bus) seem to indicate either is acceptable: *verb* Word forms: `buses,  busing,  bused,  busses,  bussing,  bussed`, although [writers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+bused%2Cwas+bussed&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=4) seem to prefer your suggested choice.

Comment: Bussed is very clumsy however you spell it.  I would never say that someone bussed to a destination.

Comment: @JamesRyan Yes; in the UK, I'd say it's rarely used in the passive, and very rarely in the active.

Comment: Essentially, the English lexicon is 'defective' (doesn't contain all the words everyone would like it to). Thus 'We submarined to Calais, hovered to Alex then camelled to Cairo' isn't acceptable.

Comment: @Edwin - I asked because I was unsure if the language was 'defective', or if my knowledge of the language was incomplete. Probably both are true :-)

Comment: Look up 'words that should exist [in English]' etc. The OED board update four times a year, and there are 'Dictionaries of Neologisms'. On the other hand, there are now over 1 000 000 words in English, usually with multiple senses, and apparently Churchill could win wars knowing a mere 15 000 of these.

Comment: @Edwin - Yes! You mean words like **laundover** (*n.*) _a sock or other (usually small) article of clothing that should have gone into the previous wash load, but didn't. Usually found when the last laundry load is on the spin cycle, sometimes resulting in a mild oath upon discovery_. I still remember these as [sniglets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sniglet).

Comment: If she took de train, you could say she was derailed.  :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While not common or current, *[train](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/train)* is a verb

> [NO OBJECT] DATED Go by train: *Charles trained to Chicago with Emily* [*Oxford Dictionary Online*]

*[American Heritage](https://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/train)* lists it without the DATED catergorization

> To travel by railroad train

You might say, *Are you going to fly or train it?*

Comment: No question. In fact, I'm more comfortable with co-opting "train" like this than I am with "bus" (which to me always carries negative connotations of [[bussing schoolchildren](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desegregation_busing)). At the margins, I suppose you could "tram it" to get across town (in the right town), rather than take a cab.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "bussing" is kissing!

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- The problem with using *train* in this way is that it is now archaic, and is almost guaranteed to provoke your interlocutor to check what exactly you mean.

Comment: @Erik: I don't know why you'd call it "archaic". Samuel R Delany is perfectly current and competent, and around 1984 he wrote [I didn't see her again till I trained across country from San Francisco one November](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+trained+across%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). It's not a very common usage, but it's quite okay.

Comment: If someone told me "I flew from Rio to Berlin then trained from Berlin to Amsterdam", I'd assume they were a touring athlete or similar stopping at various places between Berlin and Amsterdam to visit training facilities, train with different coaches and other athletes etc, learn new techniques etc.

Comment: @user568458 That is why I would tend to say *then trained it from Berlin ...* (even though the verb is often listed as *intransitive*).

Comment: As someone who works in and lives near a large city that a large number of people commute to every day, and a lot of people regularly use public transport (London), I've heard "trained" a lot, and wouldn't bat an eye-lid at a phrase like "It was pouring with rain, so John trained it to the football match."

Comment: It's used in [Threat Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_Vector), which is from 2012.

Answer (score 5):

Since AmTrak is the only cross-country passenger rail system in the United States, you could say "She **AmTraked** from San Francisco to Houston" (assuming that AmTrak serves Houston these days—it didn't when I was a college student looking for alternatives to Greyhound).

You probably don't want *trained* (which, of course, primarily means "got into athletic or working condition by practicing") or *railroaded* (which idiomatically can mean "convicted on trumped-up charges"), though either option is available if you don't mind eliciting smiles or quizzical looks before you explain "I mean, she took the train from San Francisco to Houston."

Incidentally, when I was in school and had to use Greyhound buses to get to Houston from Maryland, a common description for that mode of travel was "hopping the dog."

---

**UPDATE:** My original answer was intentionally United States–specific because the OP's question asked in particular about how to refer in one word to a train trip from San Francisco to Houston. I believe that the verb *Amtraked* would be immediately recognizable to most U.S. hearers, but it isn't in common usage, and it certainly isn't comprehensible (or apt) outside the United States.

A much more popular way (in the United States) to describe having traveled by train is "rode the rails." For example, from Edward Hungerford, "[America Goes Back to Work](http://books.google.com/books?id=_H0yAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA592&dq=%22rode+the+rails%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aQPlU-CqNsbsoAShsYCwDg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22rode%20the%20rails%22&f=false)," in *Harper's Magazine* (October 1920):

> As far as Garrison we **rode the rails** of the original main line of the Northern Pacific, and when we passed the marker for the "last spike" I was reminded of the time, away back in the eighties, that the far-seeing Henry Villard had brought the investors of the enterprise out over the ungraded track five days from St. Paul to witness the event, and how they, alarmed by the vast expanse of undeveloped territory, had telegraphed and cabled to sell their holdings, thrusting the road into a financial crisis.

From F.P. Rolf, W.H. Davenport, and P. Bowerman, [*The Modern Omnibus*](http://books.google.com/books?id=VVgYAAAAIAAJ&q=%22rode+the+rails%22&dq=%22rode+the+rails%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pf3kU8WNKYj3oAScr4GoAw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwBTgK), (1946) [snippet]:

> W. H. Davies, the most "bird-like" of living lyricists, was a cattleman, a berry-picker, a day-laborer, a "super-tramp," until his foot was cut off when he **rode the rails** in Canada.

From Charles Musser, [*Before the Nickolodeon: Edwin S. Porter and the Edison Manufacturing Company*](http://books.google.com/books?id=XGK2mx54GFwC&pg=PA263&dq=%22rode+the+rails%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Af_kU8C3HMzjoASi7ICgDw&ved=0CFAQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22rode%20the%20rails%22&f=false) (1991):

> To counter its image as a coal carrier, the Lackawanna Railroad, known as "The Road of Anthracite," developed an advertising campaign in which passenger Phoebe Snow, dressed in white, **rode the rails** and praised the line's cleanliness in such slogans as: "Says Phoebe Snow, about to go/Upon a trip to Buffalo:/'My gown stays white from morn till night/Upon the Road of Anthracite.'"

And from Wendy Z. Goldman, [Women, the State and Revolution: Soviet Family Policy and Social Life, 1917–1936](http://books.google.com/books?id=zD9p0pSBBv4C&pg=PA88&dq=%22rode+the+rails%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=swDlU-GJHcjpoATQqIG4Cg&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=%22rode%20the%20rails%22&f=false) (1993):

> Dreaming of trains and travel, Vasily ran away from home repeatedly only to return, gloomy, silent, refusing to explain where he had been. Like Grisha and Aleksei, he **rode the rails** to various towns and cities, begging and stealing to survive. He was unhappy both at home and in the children's colony.

A Google Book search for "rode the rails" also turns up such titles as  [*When Beauty Rode the Rails: An Album of Railroad Yesterdays*](http://books.google.com/books?id=3-ckAQAAIAAJ&q=%22rode+the+rails%22&dq=%22rode+the+rails%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kQPlU7mFG5H8oATo1IHwBQ&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA) (1962), [*When Fresno Rode the Rails*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ba52RAAACAAJ&dq=%22rode+the+rails%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kQPlU7mFG5H8oATo1IHwBQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwBQ) (1979), [When We Rode the Rails](http://books.google.com/books?id=IBoJAQAAMAAJ&q=%22rode+the+rails%22&dq=%22rode+the+rails%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kQPlU7mFG5H8oATo1IHwBQ&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ) (1983), [*When Eastern Michigan Rode the Rails*](http://books.google.com/books?id=tnjhAAAAMAAJ&q=%22rode+the+rails%22&dq=%22rode+the+rails%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kQPlU7mFG5H8oATo1IHwBQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw) (1984), and [*Victory Rode the Rails: The Strategic Place of the Railroads in the Civil War*](http://books.google.com/books?id=FpINOwAACAAJ&dq=%22rode+the+rails%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kQPlU7mFG5H8oATo1IHwBQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA) (1992). Part of the appeal of the phrase "rode the rails," I suspect, is that it sounds like a gentle play on the word *railroad*.

It's worth noting that "riding the rails" is especially associated with hobos who traveled (illegally and for free) by boarding freight trains as they pulled out of train yards after loading or unloading their cars of freight; this act is also known as "hopping a freight." I don't know whether the phrase "riding the rails" is common outside North America.

As for single-word terms for traveling by train, I agree with Erik Kowal that there aren't any truly satisfactory ones in common usage.

Comment: But.. what if you're in China? Or India?

Comment: @slebetman (and the four upvoters of slebetman's comment): See the update to my original answer (above).

Answer (score 3):

There's currently no analogous equivalent to *bus(s)ed, flew* or *flown* in everyday use that relates to train travel. The best alternatives I can think of that might normally be employed are *travel(l)ed, took, transported,* and *conveyed*. Compare:

> 1) "She was bussed from San Francisco to Houston"
>
> 2) "She flew from San Francisco to Houston"
>
> 3) "She was flown from San Francisco to Houston"
>
> 4) "She travelled by train from London to Edinburgh"
>
> 5) "She took the train from London to Edinburgh"
>
> 6) "She was transported by train from London to Edinburgh"
>
> 7) "She was conveyed by train from London to Edinburgh"

Of those four alternatives, 4) and 5) are the most idiomatic in British and American English, 6) the least.

Comment: 6 might be the best if ‘she’ is Dolly the cloned sheep being transported to Edinburgh for some testing purpose or other. Also, “She went from London to Edinburgh by train” is tied with 4 for most natural to my ear, more likely than 5.

Answer (score 1):

*[Entrain](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entrain#Verb)*, with senses  “(poetic, intransitive) To get into or board a railway train” and “(transitive) To put aboard a railway train” seems a slight possibility.  For example:

> She entrained at San Francisco for Houston.
>   She entrained herself at San Francisco for Houston.

Comment: A slight possibility of ... a grammatical construction? Did she sleep furiously on the train? 38 Google hits for "She entrained at" – and I'm guessing they're mostly historical sources.